# How to show this determinant $D \not= 0$ (EDIT) maybe figure out is impossible

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

SORRY, I made a typo. it should be $D \not= 0$,not $D>0$.

It is a bit like Vandermonde determinant
$$D=$$
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3&\cdots &2008&2009 & 2010 & 2011\\ 
2^2 & 3^2 &4^2& \cdots&2009^2&2010^2 & 2011^2 &2012^2 \\ 
3^3 & 4^3 &5^3&\cdots  &2010^3&2011^3&2012^3  &2012^3 \\ 
\cdots &\cdots  &\cdots  &\cdots&\cdots&\cdots  &\cdots &\cdots\\
k^k&(k+1)^k&\cdots&2011^k&2012^k&\cdots&2012^k&2012^k\\
\cdots &\cdots  &\cdots  &\cdots  &\cdots &\cdots\\
2010^{2010}&2011^{2010}&2012^{2010}&\cdots&2012^{2010}&2012^{2010}&2012^{2010}&2012^{2010}\\ 
2011^{2011} &2012^{2011}  &2012^{2011}&\cdots  &2012^{2011}  &2012^{2011} &2012^{2011}&2012^{2011}
\end{vmatrix}$$

Is the above determinant $D\not= 0$?

the exam is only need to show $D \not= 0$,maybe figure out $D$ is impossible. and I edit it, maybe more clearly.

thanks for comments and answer.

FIRST PAGE OF EXAM:

[image]

Comment: The pattern isn't clear. It looks like the diagonals are increasing powers of a fixed base, but also it looks like the lower right half is all powers of $2012$. By the way, this isn't a contest problem, is it?

Comment: yes,the diagonals are increasing powers of a fixed base $2011$, thanks for your comment,I will modify it. and it is a contest problem.

Comment: A problem from an ongoing contest? Is there a link to a contest website?

Comment: OK,it is a graduate entrance exam of Peking university in 2012. but there is no official version. and there is a link to its original which is recalled by candidate:http://www.math.org.cn/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=23291&extra=&page=1. you can find it from the PDF file. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am posting this as an answer since it is too long for a comment. In general, note that $$A_{n+1} = \begin{bmatrix} A_n & u_n\\
v_n & (2n+3)^{n+2}\end{bmatrix}$$
where 
$$u_n = \begin{bmatrix}(n+2)\\(n+3)^2\\ (n+4)^3\\ \vdots \\ (2n+2)^{n+1} \end{bmatrix}$$
$$v_n = \begin{bmatrix} (n+2)^{n+2} & (n+3)^{n+2} & (n+3)^{n+2} & \cdots & (2n+1)^{n+2} & (2n+2)^{n+2}\end{bmatrix}$$
and $A_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix}$. I computed the value of determinant for $A_k$ for $k=0$ to $k=5$ using MATLAB and below are the values.

$$\det(A_0) = 1; \det(A_1) = 1; \det(A_2) = 4; \det(A_3) = 72; \det(A_4) = 6912; \det(A_5) = 4147200$$
$$\det(A_6) = 17915904000;$$

[Feeding this sequence in OEIS gave that a possible sequence is](http://oeis.org/search?q=1,1,4,72,6912&sort=&language=english&go=Search)
$$\det(A_{n-1}) = (n-1)! \times \prod_{k=1}^{n-2} (n-k)!$$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Once we have this, we can hope for a proof by induction.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying the pattern for me? I interpreted $A_2$ as $$A_2=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2^2 & 3^2 & 4^2 \\ 3^3 & 4^3 & 4^3\end{pmatrix}$$ but that gives me a determinant of $-57$.

Comment: Agreeing with EuYu. OP has not made things completely clear, but the bottom row in the body of the question doesn't look like the $v_n$ in the answer. However, the strategy of calculating the first few and then consulting the oracle at oeis may well pay off.

Comment: The sequence as I interpreted it seems to give $$1,\ 1,\ -57,\ -49099,\ 820631141,\ \cdots$$ Doesn't seem familiar to oeis.

Comment: @EuYu, your $++--$ pattern seems simple enough. I pasted the first page of the examination into the question.

Comment: I am sorry. I made a typo. it need to prove $D \not=0$,not $D >0$.

Comment: @R_bot Well, proving $D>0$ certainly proves $D\neq 0$ so I guess no real harm done.

Comment: maybe it $<0$. I used maxima to computer a similar determinant $$D_4=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4\cr 2^2 & 3^2 & 4^2 & 5^2\cr 3^3 & 4^3 & 5^3 & 6^3\cr 4^4 & 5^4 & 6^4 & 6^4\end{pmatrix}<0$$, and when $n=2011$,$D_{2011}$ may $<0$. thank you

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the first 20 items in the obvious sequence, computed using

```
f[n_] := Det[Table[If[i + j - 1 > n, n + 1, i + j - 1]^i, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]]
```

in *Mathematica*, are

\begin{gather}\small
 1 \\\small
 1 \\\small
 -57 \\\small
 -49099 \\\small
 820631141 \\\small
 327729323411785 \\\small
 -3722810907570484463905 \\\small
 -1395732893854465247614690459535 \\\small
 19654898955250800722122617078850379547649 \\\small
 11654863933592492659392873622726534581699247698016601 \\\scriptsize
 -322373512908450688046702815032229983463944019597828165058661862873 \\\scriptsize
 -456322749650163764951140063242869266114020813743510155958815030863103530198278707
   \\\scriptsize
   359763590088436766228887856876796313253226027493473716114855323607493415839311215
   63741918002361805 \\\scriptsize
   170784854835456576916145215980211059998029046033398578352565914083160320685101869
   469195969039220374230020741584750601 \\\scriptsize
   -52473397006405670917113840563365195251372913721092487498198489291680306518569632
   237546150574105804810447098763276030563961357045407349377 \\\scriptsize
   -11161338095346579407742610541224509857161891767489700245561198039424133307461760
   19001249905947908531883035800858849726377707025535086543207728368627630155179671
   \\\tiny
   175043317755348307253812637289721345473677623476953037216431178436787653927346563
   419897174832441679689898012101336598764499805173923767791098038693711420817887509
   1111661312135016606441 \\
\end{gather}

Comment: thank you. your calculation have reminded me that i made a typo. it should to prove $D\not=0$,not $D>0$. I am sorry for my mistake...

Comment: @R_bot, I posted the first page of the examination at the end of your question. Please make your very best, most careful translation of the question 2 text and edit it into your question just before the JPEG. If you need help with a good quality translation get it.

Comment: thank you. Will Jagy. I had modified a typo. now I can ensure there is no translate error.